# Как преобразовать формат данных в файлах 1С?

Tags: 1с, sql, сервер

Как преобразовать данные, представленные в файлах 1с в двоичном формате в читаемый текстовый формат?

Я перекопировал в программу Access данные 1С 8.1 из таблиц SQL SERVER. Однако текстовые данные представлены в двоичном формате. Мне нужен принцип перекодировки этой информации в читаемый текстовый формат. Тогда я смогу написать программу перекодировки в Access.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего через COM-сервер 1С.
Работать непосредственно с базой SQL не рекомендуется, потому как при очередном обновлении наименование таблиц могут измениться :) Я уже не говорю о том, что попытка произвести запись в таблицы из сторонней программы может разрушить базу.